# Python Typing: List of specific values

Tags: python, types, literals, type-hinting

I want to type a variable to be list of finite set of valid values.
So basically, I would like to have the typing equivalent of the following minimal example:

```
valid_parameters = ["value", "other value"]

def check_type(parameters_list):
    for parameter in parameters_list:
        if parameter not in valid_parameters:
            raise ValueError("invalid parameter")

valid_list = ["value"]
check_type(valid_list)
# work

invalid_list = ["different_value"]
check_type(invalid_list)
# raise error
```

I checked typing already, but I didn't manage to find a solution. I tried to create list of `Literal`, but it didn't seem to work. Is there such a solution? Can it be created?

Comment: When you say that "it didn't seem to work" with `Literal`, what is the behavior you notice and what were you expecting? Because `Literal` seems to be what is used to address cases like yours.

Comment: `lit = Literal['a', 'b']`,  `my_list: List[lit] =  ['a']` - don't match, but `var = 'a'` with `my_list: List[lit] =  [var]` seems to work, somehow...

Comment: Are you using PyCharm? Because I do, indeed, have the same behavior in PyCharm and it seems to be a bug. 
This line: `my_list: List[Literal["a", "b", "c"]] = ["a"]` raises the following warning: `Expected type 'List[Literal["a", "b", "c"]]', got 'List[str]' instead`

Comment: I would create a new class that wraps a list, with a method that checks items as you try to add them to the list in the first place, rather than using a raw list.

Comment: @user1997656 did my suggestion below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Using `Literal` won't work during runtime, [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) are meant to be used with type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

Hence the following will not fail during runtime:

```
>>> from typing import Literal
>>> VALID = Literal["value", "other value"]
>>> def foo(my_param: VALID) -> None:
...     print(my_param)
... 
>>> foo("value")
value
>>> foo("bar")
bar
```

But you can use an `Enum` to achieve what you want:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class Parameter(Enum):
...     VALUE = "value"
...     OTHER_VALUE = "other value"
... 
>>> def foo(my_param: Parameter) -> None:
...     print(my_param)
...
>>> foo(Parameter("value"))
Parameter.VALUE
>>> foo(Parameter("wrong"))
ValueError: 'wrong' is not a valid Parameter
```

(This was tested on Python 3.8.0)